# Which type of factorization is appropriate?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

I have a symmetric matrix (square)($A$) with positive values and zero on its main diagonal. I need to find a matrix $Y$ which is:

$Y^TY = A$

I don't have any non-negativity constraint on the elements of $Y$. I know just a little about matrix factorization and most of the search results are about non-negative matrix factorization. It should be noted that I can't prove that $A$ is positive semi-definite or something like that to use eigen-vectors. Is there any keyword or solution which help me with the problem?

Comment: If $Y$ is a real matrix, then $Y^T Y$ is positive semidefinite.  So if $A$ is not positive semidefinite, you're out of luck.

Comment: @RobertIsrael But what if you allow $Y$ to be complex? Does a decomposition exist in all cases then?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for your response, but what if Y to be complex? And is there anyway to force a matrix to be positive semidefinite?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Or any approximation for it.

Comment: If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, then it has a (complex) symmetric square root $Y$ which can be defined using the holomorphic functional calculus.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Can you give me some reference or method name? Isn't it related to SVD? Is it possible to use the real part to approximate?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus).  The real part is not a good approximation unless the negative eigenvalues of $A$ are close to $0$.